# How can I create a unit test to test for a RedirectToActionResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I've created an `async Task<ActionResult>` create method that has a user input data with the data saved to an azure table. I need to unit test it to show that it redirects to the Index

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Create")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateAsync([Bind(Include = "Id,StudentNo,Name,Surname,Email,Telephone,Mobile,Active")] Item item)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        await DocumentDBRepository<Item>.CreateItemAsync(item);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(item);
}
```

Comment: And the problem is...?

Comment: what is the problem here?

Comment: i' ve been looking online for a way to implement my test but cant seem to find anything that applies to my scenario, a way to code the test is the help i need

Comment: Create the controller under test. Inject/setup any dependencies needed for the test to flow as expected. assert the result of exercising the method under test.

Comment: how do u write that code exactly?

Comment: in this case it would depend on a few things. what is `DocumentDBRepository<Item>`? can it be mocked to behave as expected when testing in isolation?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to unit test it to show that it redirects to the Index

Then do UI unit testing like `Jasmin` cause server side unit testing isn't meant for that cause while in test there is no MVC pipeline exists and does all this route, httpcontext etc doesn't exists at all. rather you should concentrate on unit testing the business logic

Comment: If you wanted to include the MVC pipeline, wouldn't that make it more of an integration test? I don't see a problem unit testing this...

Comment: @JohnOsborne run the test case and see if httpcontext is present or not?

Comment: You would create unit tests for your controller. so... `MyController controllerUnderTest = new MyController(stuff);` then you could call `CreateAsync()` and test that your `RedirectToActionResult` had a ViewName of `"Index"`

Comment: you could use Moq to Mock<HttpContext> if you needed to

Answer (score 0):

Check for actual type of the returned result

```
public async Task ShouldRedirect()
{
    var controller = new Controller();

    var result = await controller.Create(item);

    result.Should().BeOfType<RedirectToRouteResult>();
}
```